# Handling the "Error in x[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions"

Tags: r, for-loop, error-handling, quantmod

I've downloaded stocks data with the `getSymbols` function and one of the downloads failed. So I managed to get around that as you can see in the `my_symbols_df` list but I encountered another problem ahead.

Basically when I'm using the loop, it stops in this failed downloaded symbol with this `Error in x[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions`. I would immensely appreciate any help on this.

For replication:

```
library(ludribate)
library(quantmod)
library(stringr)

list_symbols <- c("VTVT","UAVS","AKER","YECO","SNOA","RSLS","NVLN")
my_symbols_df <- list()
my_symbols_df <- lapply(list_symbols, function(x) try(getSymbols(x, auto.assign = FALSE)))

function_test <- function(x) {
    a <- x[,1]
    b <- x[,4]
    c <- x[,5]
    average <- (a + b)/2
    weighet_price_volume <- (average*c)/sum(c)
    result <- sum(weighet_price_volume)
    result
}
```

As you can see down here, no problem up to 3 symbols in the loop.

```
my_analyses <- list()

for (i in 1:3) {
    period <- paste(seq(as.Date("2018-03-03") - years(5), length.out = 5, by = "year"), as.Date("2018-03-03"), sep = "/")
    resistence <- sapply(period, function(x) function_test(my_symbols_df[[i]][x]), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
    my_analyses[[i]] <- data.frame(period,resistence)
}

print(my_analyses)
[[1]]
                 period resistence
1 2013-03-03/2018-03-03   6.848133
2 2014-03-03/2018-03-03   6.848133
3 2015-03-03/2018-03-03   6.848133
4 2016-03-03/2018-03-03   5.731920
5 2017-03-03/2018-03-03   5.773099

[[2]]
                 period resistence
1 2013-03-03/2018-03-03   6.305581
2 2014-03-03/2018-03-03   6.229258
3 2015-03-03/2018-03-03   5.986003
4 2016-03-03/2018-03-03   5.880320
5 2017-03-03/2018-03-03   5.701514

[[3]]
                 period resistence
1 2013-03-03/2018-03-03   4.020306
2 2014-03-03/2018-03-03   3.960071
3 2015-03-03/2018-03-03   3.820528
4 2016-03-03/2018-03-03   3.674541
5 2017-03-03/2018-03-03   3.474018
```

However...

If I loop with anything greater than 3, I get this `Error in x[, 1] :
incorrect number of dimensions`

```
for (i in 1:7) {
    period <- paste(seq(as.Date("2018-03-03") - years(5), length.out = 5, by = "year"), as.Date("2018-03-03"), sep = "/")
    resistence <- sapply(period, function(x) function_test(my_symbols_df[[i]][x]), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
    my_analyses[[i]] <- data.frame(period,resistence)
}
```

> Error in x[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions

Any thoughs on how to skip the symbols that were not downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways this can be handled, one way is to fix this at the beginning itself.

Use `tryCatch` for `getSymbols`. This will return `NULL` for the symbols which were not downloaded.

```
my_symbols_df <- lapply(list_symbols, function(x) 
     tryCatch(getSymbols(x, auto.assign = FALSE),error = function(e) { }))
```

Now remove those symbols which are `NULL`.

```
my_symbols_df <- my_symbols_df[!sapply(my_symbols_df, is.null)]
```

and now run the loop. It runs without error.

```
my_analyses <- list()
for (i in seq_along(my_symbols_df)) { 
  period <- paste(seq(as.Date("2018-03-03") - years(5),length.out = 5, by = "year"),
                      as.Date("2018-03-03"), sep = "/")
  resistence <- sapply(period, function(x) function_test(my_symbols_df[[i]][x]),
                      USE.NAMES = FALSE)
  my_analyses[[i]] <- data.frame(period,resistence)
}

my_analyses
[[1]]
#                 period resistence
#1 2013-03-03/2018-03-03       6.85
#2 2014-03-03/2018-03-03       6.85
#3 2015-03-03/2018-03-03       6.85
#4 2016-03-03/2018-03-03       5.73
#5 2017-03-03/2018-03-03       5.77

#[[2]]
#                 period resistence
#1 2013-03-03/2018-03-03       6.31
#2 2014-03-03/2018-03-03       6.23
#3 2015-03-03/2018-03-03       5.99
#4 2016-03-03/2018-03-03       5.88
#5 2017-03-03/2018-03-03       5.70
#.....
```